# Read CSV malformed (3 csv concatenated) in a single URL call

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read this CSV:
https://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/api/tmy?lat=41&lon=22&startyear=2007

And right now I'm doing 3 calls to parse it, since its structure is inconsistent. (they are basically 3 csv concatenated, with 3 indexes in between)

```
url = 'https://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/api/tmy?lat=41&lon=22&startyear=2007'
MetaData = pd.read_csv(url,sep=":", nrows=3,names=['key','value'])
# do something with metadata
MonthData = pd.read_csv(url,skiprows=3,nrows=12)
# do something with the year 
Data = pd.read_csv(url,skiprows=16, skipfooter=11, engine='python')
# do something with the actual data
```

Is there a better way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pvlib.iotools.get_pvgis_tmy`](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pvlib.iotools.get_pvgis_tmy.html)

```py
from pvgis.iotools import get_pvgis_tmy

lat=41
lon=22
startyear=2007

data, months, inputs, meta = get_pvgis_tmy(lat, lon, startyear=startyear)
```

[This example and its output are in this Google Colaboratory Notebook: `SO-get_pvgis.ipynb`](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ba_guD2cDFlT0kppXz_CkoXPGeNwzzjk)

Here are some plots form the notebook comparing the PVGIS components with predictions from Haurwitz and Erbs:

#### Compare GHI

[image: compare GHI]

#### Compare DNI

[image: compare DNI]

#### Compare DHI

[image: compare DHI]

If you're more interested in the codebase, check out [the pvlib source at GitHub](https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python/blob/3ce8e1a5e5db42d09982e0153b65b4a8547180fa/pvlib/iotools/pvgis.py#L27) and contribute!

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Mark. I replaced my data source and it works like a charm. That said I see a discrepancy between my previous datasource and this new one. When I try to use Ineichen to predict the irradiation information, G(h) and Gb(h) matches, but Gd(h) and the respective predicted dhi are different (although correlated). An image here: https://ibb.co/YR5yBCW

Comment: HI @Snick sorry to be petty, but if this answers your question, and you please check it off? Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the image, I think you should post this in a new SO question with the [pvlib] label so it get's as much attention as possible. Also, I think you should post this on [the pvlib Google Groups forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pvlib-python) - so that we can give it the attention it deserves, thanks!

Comment: Hi @Snick [Ineichen](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pvlib.clearsky.ineichen.html) is sensitive to inputs. [Simplified Solis](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pvlib.clearsky.simplified_solis.html) is recommended. I used a simple model, Haurwitz and Erbs, and I get pretty good agreement between PVGIS and predicted clear sky, [see the notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ba_guD2cDFlT0kppXz_CkoXPGeNwzzjk)

Comment: thank you again for all the very useful input. I'd love to learn more about all the different prediction systems available in PVLIB, not just what is available in the library docs, but more on the ground real world experience. where would be the best place to go to?

Comment: I think [the pvlib Google Groups forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pvlib-python) is a great place for discussion, there are many experts there who have been working on PV, solar-energy/power, irradiance, forecasting, and more for 30+ years, and are often happy and eager to share their experience. Also the [PV Performance Modeling Collaborative](https://pvpmc.sandia.gov/) hosted by Sandia NL has [workshops](https://pvpmc.sandia.gov/resources-and-events/events/) every year. If you repost this question in the forum you'll get more detailed and varied answers. :)